# Seek help regarding Robocopy commands

Tags: robocopy

I'm using `Robocopy` to `move` a file from its source to destination. However if this movement were to be interrupted I want it to resume later from the point at which the interruption occurred. For instance, if the movement were to be  interrupted when it's 45% done, I want the movement to be carried forth from 45% when I run it again and not begin from 0% all over again.

I'm using the following command for it in SQL:

`EXEC MASTER..XP_CMDSHELL 'ROBOCOPY <source> <destination> <file_to_be_moved> /mov /zb /r:3 /w:1 /v /eta /log:"<log_file_path>"'`

I wish to know if I'm on the right track with this command. As the file to be copied is humongous and I do not want to risk losing any of its contents.

PS. I do know /zb is for restart mode cum backup mode!

Answer (score 1):

That should work. [`/ZB`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx)  (or more importantly, the `Z` part) is what enables you to restart from where you left off. I think I've had trouble with `/ZB` in the past, but `/Z` always worked fine.

I always thought the `/Z` switch for **Restart mode** didn't make any sense, so in my head I refer to it as **Zombie mode** because it comes back to life if it gets killed halfway through!

You should be able to run a quick test. Try copying a dummy file using the command you've used, then `CTRL+C` to end it before it finishes. Start the copy back up, and make sure it doesn't start over from the beginning.